Can a thunderstorm affect a satellite in low earth orbit?
Clouds build up strong static electric charges. Magnetism is an emergent phenomenon of the length contraction of electric fields. Due to the strength of EM interaction, even very slow movement can result in strong magnetic fields, such as that caused by electrons moving at drift speed through the wires of electromagnets.
So, wouldn't satellites be subject to easily detectable magnetic forces from clouds due to their high speed around the earth, if they were to pass over a thunderstorm?

Thera are two effects of thumderstorms that spread above troposphere. First are "sprites" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_(lightning). But sprites don't reach orbital heights. The second phenomena are "terrestrial gamma ray flashes" TGF https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_gamma-ray_flash. They were discovered by Fermi gamma ray orbital observatory, and probably associated with thunderstorms (but it's not certain). But looks like TGF are not intensive enough to have effects on orbiting satellites

By coincidence, a headline at Scientific American today reads "Lightning on Earth Knocks ‘Killer Electrons’ Loose in Orbit". It seems a bit overblown to me. Electron fluxes in LEO are variable for a variety of reasons, but they are rarely "killers".

The title of your intriguing question uses "affect" but in the body of the question you use "detect". I think that detection of something is a subset of being affected by something. For example, The Moon's gravity affects me, but without some additional equipment, I can't detect it. If I build a crystal radio set, I can detect AM radio signals (in more ways than one) but unless I'm listening, those radio waves don't affect me (to the best of my knowledge).

The recent paper in Nature that the SciAm article links to is Open Access, Lightning-induced relativistic electron precipitation from the inner radiation belt Rather than dismiss the quite high energy electron bursts as "variability", perhaps something more quantitative is helpful. A several MeV electron can pass through a non-trivial amount of metal and then produce a non-trivial amount of ionization in semiconductor material inside.

That sounds unlikely but doesn't it depend on the actual circumstances?
Can you describe the size and strength of the thunderstorm?
Can you describe the characteristics of the satellite?
Can you specify the radius of low-Earth orbit?

@RobbieGoodwin: Well, for the sake of argument, imagine the satellite at the lowest possible orbit and the storm accumulating as much charge as possible. Sorry, not a physicist, please accept my humble spherical cow.

Well, for the sake of argument, do imagine the satellite at the lowest possible orbit and the storm accumulating as much charge as possible.
In such a case do you have an Answer to offer?
In any case, what's a 'spherical cow'?

@RobbieGoodwin Spherical cow and different but related: Back-of-the-envelope

Thanks and that Link seems to make it clear, your spherical cow has nothing to offer here. Does that much work for you?
Again, can you describe the size and strength of the thunderstorm? Can you describe the characteristics of the satellite? Can you specify the radius of low-Earth orbit?

Can we go back and define 'low Earth orbit', please?
To me, one of the differences between low and high orbit - and on to outer space - is whether a thunderstorm can affect any object.

Satellites in a low Earth orbit (LEO) have orbits between ~300km and 1200km height (lower orbits are unstable due to increased atmospheric drag). Consider this distance on the ground: you are often in another country or state, driving for hours or a full day on a highway to cover that distance. How much would a thunderstorm at the origin affect you (or e.g. your radio's perception) when you are at the destination? Thus the weather in the lower part of the atmosphere (lower 20km) is not of concern for satellites.
The charging of the spacecraft in the magnetosphere of Earth and / or solar wind is of far bigger importance and in part a design driver. The exposure of the satellite to magnetic storms coming from the Sun does pose a threat to space craft which could in essence short-circuit their electronics with high voltages or currents induced (which is simply speaking the same as usual, charges impinging on the SC, just much more intense).

We can certainly detect a thunderstorm 300–1200 km away, and lightning strikes more than 700 km long have been detected.

@gerrit of course we can detect it. And that's what especially earth observation satellites do. But "being able to detect" is a way different category than "being (adversely) affected by".

That depends on what you are trying to detect.  In principle, anything that is detectable can be noise when trying to detect something else, in particular if that other thing looks similar.  For an optical detection system for bolides, lightning is a source of noise.  But that's probably not what the OP means.

@gerrit yes, but that only happens because the storm itself is 700km long. The distance that matters is how far to the closest part of the storm. When you're looking 700km up, that doesn't apply anymore.

I feel like saying "You wouldn't hear lightning 300 km away on the ground so obviously you wouldn't see any effects 300 km up" is very hand-wavey--you may as well answer "can you breathe in space" with "LEO is only 300 km away--if you can breathe in LA and San Francisco, you're actually closer to space than the distance between those two cities." Up is different from sideways, the ground interacts with EM different from air and vacuum, and satellites are going a lot faster than a car

@Kaia It may be handwavy, and I chose it to visualize the distance we talk about. For sound it makes a difference - but not so much for the electromagnetic waves which matter here (though air also attenuates those also somewhat). Either way: impactful is not the weather in the troposphere, but interaction with Earth's magnetosphere and the electron and proton fluxes, especially in solar storm conditions. The distance to those conditions might be: 0km.

The recent paper in Nature is Open Access, Here we present direct measurements of MeV electron microbursts from the inner radiation belt driven by lightning. In searching for bouncing packets in the SAMPEX/HILT (Solar Anomalous and Magnetospheric Particle EXplorer/Heavy Ion Large Telescope) ≥ 1 MeV electron dataset, measured from a low-altitude (520 × 670 km), high-inclination orbit... I think the ratio of this answer's hand-waving to supporting source-citing is in the stratosphere.

Perhaps first read the article thoroughly, then see how well this answer stands up?

Another problem with your assertion is the curvature of the earth. An atmospheric event (like an electric storm) can be visible from above at far greater distances than it can be from below. And because of the lower atmospheric density up there some such phenomena may well be attenuated less than they are on the surface (others require air to propagate and won't reach orbital altitudes unless maybe very low orbit and greatly attenuated).
